# R function to group data and summarize by time interval in another column

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have data in the following format :

[image]

The first column is the ID of an individual with his BMI measured at different times in the column Date. I want to take an average of the BMI over a period of one year, i.e 6 months before and 6 months after the Date_of_diagnosis. Note that the date of diagnosis is the same date.

The expected output is something like:

```
ID   Date         BMI    Date_of_diagnosis Avg BMI
718  07-01-1994   28.75  13-12-1999        25.8
718  07-01-1994   28.75  13-12-1999
718  07-01-1994   28.75   13-12-1999
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also, show expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use dput. I have added the expected output.

Comment: If the interval is 6 months before/after like you have mentioned then the given example does not represent a right output because it is 1999 and 1994.

Comment: If your dataframe is called `df` run `dput(df)` in the console, copy the output and paste it here Or just share the data the same way you have shared expected output so that it is easy to copy-paste instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a method using dplyr;

Note that there are lots of functions in R that can provide months between two dates in months, however mostly they assume the 30 days months that's why I prefer to build a custom function but you are free to use any function

Also here I made the interval less/more are equal to each other as specified but you can change that by setting another variable.

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample of the input data
data <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(718, 718, 718),
    Date = lubridate::dmy(c("07-01-1994", "07-01-1994", "07-01-1994")),
    BMI = c(28.75, 28.75, 28.75),
    Date_of_diagnosis = lubridate::dmy(c("13-12-1999", "13-12-1999", "13-12-1999"))
  )

# Function to calculate months between 2 dates in months
months_between <- function(end_date, start_date) {
  ed <- as.POSIXlt(end_date)
  sd <- as.POSIXlt(start_date)
  12 * (ed$year - sd$year) + (ed$mon - sd$mon)
}

# Setting the interval i.e. 72 months before/after diagnosis
num_months <- 72

data %>%
  # If the difference between diagnosis and date is less/more than Date by num_month
  # then consider the BMI
  mutate(avg_bmi = 
           ifelse(between(months_between(Date_of_diagnosis, Date), 0, num_months) |
                    between(months_between(Date_of_diagnosis, Date), -1 * num_months, 0), 
                  BMI, NA)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% # To calculate for each ID
  mutate(avg_bmi = mean(avg_bmi, na.rm = TRUE)) # Calculating average BMI for interval

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   ID [1]
# ID Date         BMI Date_of_diagnosis avg_bmi
# <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>              <dbl>
# 718 1994-01-07  28.8 1999-12-13           28.8
# 718 1994-01-07  28.8 1999-12-13           28.8
# 718 1994-01-07  28.8 1999-12-13           28.8
```